# Explicit formulas for Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I have seen some recursive formulas for Stirling I and II kind but I am especially interested in explicit formulas.

I was thinking and get:
$$ \left\{ {m \atop n} \right\} =  \sum_{k_i>0 \wedge k_1+k_2+...+k_n = m} \frac{m!}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{k_1! \cdot k_2! \cdot ... \cdot k_n!}$$
I am not sure if it is ok but supposedly it is (I created it with combinatorics interpretation) 
Can somebody look at that and tell me if it is ok/wrong?

By the way,if you have some nice formulas, I will be grateful for sharing that.

Comment: Look up Wikipedia.

Comment: If there were easy explicit formulas, they would be on Wikipedia.

Comment: How about that formula which I posted? I can't find that on wikipedia.

Comment: There’s a very nice single summation formula for Stirling numbers of the second kind on Wikipedia, in the Definition  section https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition

Comment: Ok, it is very nice, but formula which I posted is correct?

Comment: Edited post for check my formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed formula is correct: see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) the exponential generating function for the Stirling numbers of second kind:
\begin{align*} \sum_{n\ge k} {n \brace k}\frac{x^n}{n!}&= \frac{\left(e^x-1\right)^k}{k!}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{j\ge1}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^k.\end{align*}
Just expand the right hand side and equate the coefficient of $x^n$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

A probabilistic proof/interpretation (perhaps this is how you got it?). We consider the experiment of placing $m$ balls into $n$ urns (with uniform probability). The distribution is the [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution): $$P(x_1,x_2 \cdots x_n) = \frac{m!}{x_1 ! x_2! \cdots x_n!} \frac{1}{n^m} \, \left[\sum{x_i}=m\right] \left[0\le x_i \le m \right] \tag1$$

Now, consider the event $E$ that all urns are not empty. Its probability, by the combinatorial interpretation of Stirling numbers of the second kind, is $$P(E)=P(x_1>0,x_2>0\cdots)= \frac{n!{m \brace n}}{n^m} \tag2$$

But from $(1)$

$$P(E)=   \sum_{x_i>0 \wedge x_1+x_2+...+x_n = m} \frac{m!}{n^m}\frac{1}{x_1! \cdot x_2! \cdot ... \cdot x_n!} \tag3$$

Equating the RHS of $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get your formula.